# KendoUI Grid Foreign Key not refreshing

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having an issue with the Grid widget in KendoUI. I have two grids on my page, each representing a table in the database. The second of these grids contains a foreign key column linking it to the first. When I add or update a row in the first grid, I want the dropdown for the foreign key in the second grid to refresh but I can't seem to get that to happen without a full page refresh (which I am trying to avoid). I can get the grid itself to refresh correctly using the JavaScript method but the dropwonlist values for the foreign key do not change.

Page code:

```
<div id="TableResults" style="height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SRSDatabaseCore.Data.TranslationTable>()
   .Name("translationGrid")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Sequence);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
   })
   .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Batch(true)
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Model(model => 
      {
        model.Id(p => p.Id);
        model.Field(field => field.Id).Editable(false);
      })
      .Create(create => create.Action("Create_TranslationTable", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
      .Read(read => read.Action("Read_TranslationTable", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
      .Update(update => update.Action("Update_TranslationTable", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
   )
   .ToolBar(toolbar =>
   {
     toolbar.Create();
     toolbar.Save();
   })
   .Events(e => e.DataBound("onTranslationModify"))
   .Pageable()
   .Sortable()
)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SRSDatabaseCore.Data.TranslationTableSource>()
  .Name("translationSourceGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
     columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
     columns.ForeignKey(p => p.TranslationTableId, new SelectList((@ViewData["TranslationTableRows"] as List<SRSDatabaseCore.Data.TranslationTable>), "Id", "Description"));
     columns.Bound(p => p.Value);
  })
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Batch(true)
     .ServerOperation(false)
     .Model(model => 
     {
        model.Id(p => p.Id);
        model.Field(field => field.Id).Editable(false);
     })
     .Create(create => create.Action("Create_TranslationTableSource", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
     .Read(read => read.Action("Read_TranslationTableSource", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
     .Update(update => update.Action("Update_TranslationTableSource", "Modify", new { tableName = ViewData["SelectedTableName"] }))
  )
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
     toolbar.Create();
     toolbar.Save();
  })
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
)
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onTranslationModify(e) {
   var sourceGrid = $('#translationSourceGrid').data('kendoGrid');
   sourceGrid.dataSource.page(1);
   sourceGrid.dataSource.read();
}
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Read_TranslationTableSource([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string tableName)
   {
      IEnumerable<TranslationTable> translationTables = DatabaseStructure.GetTranslationTableByName(GetClientNameFromCookie(), tableName, SysConnection);
      ViewData["TranslationTableRows"] = translationTables;

      List<TranslationTableSource> TranslationTableSourceRows = DatabaseStructure.GetTranslationTableSourceByTranslationTableName(GetClientNameFromCookie(), tableName, SysConnection);
      ViewData["SelectedTableName"] = tableName;

      return Json(TranslationTableSourceRows.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request));
   }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below answer, I think it will solve your issue,

[Kendo Grid Foreign key column bind dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012600/kendo-grid-foreign-key-column-bind-dynamically)