# Add DropDownList as column in KendoUI grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm working with KendoUI and MVC 5

I have a server-side model like this

```
public class ApplicationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ApplicationVersionModel MinVersion { get; set; }
    public ApplicationVersionModel CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationVersionModel> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

with ApplicationVersionModel set up like this

```
public class ApplicationVersionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to build a grid using KendoUI with a possibility to perform an inline edit with DropDownList for my MinVersion and CurrentVersion fields.
Example [grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) on the Telerik's website uses static data source for each row's dropdown while I need to bind each row to it's Versions property.

UPDATE:

`Model` is `IEnumerable<ApplicationModel>`

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
      columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CurrentVersion, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["something"], "Id", "Number");
  })
```

I need somehow to tell my grid that datasource is `p => p.Versions` instead of `ViewData["something"]`. Each row (ApplicationModel) has it's own list of versions in my case. Can't find necessary overload for this

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: You need to look at that the [Foreign Key Column](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn) example. That will help you achieve what you want to do

Comment: @codingbadger have a look at update please

Comment: You will probably have to create a custom editor template and bind the dropdowns using AJAX http://stackoverflow.com/a/21013715/300863